# When should the dimens.xml file be used in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, dimensions

For instance, in a specific layout I have the following XML:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:columnWidth="48dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidth" />
```

This grid view is specific to this layout and I don't think I'll be using any other grid views with similar properties. That to say that the dimension values in the code are specific to that grid view.

Should I still move them to a dimens.xml file or it's fine to just leave them like that? If so, should I place values in the dimens.xml file only when that value is used across multiple layouts?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I drop dimension values into a `dimens.xml` resource typically for three reasons:

1. **Reuse:** I need multiple widgets or layouts to use the same value and I only want to change it once when updating or tweaking across the application.
2. **Density Difference:** If I need the dimension to be slightly smaller or larger from `ldpi -> hdpi` or `small -> large`.
3. **Reading in from code:** When I'm instantiating a view in the code and want to apply some static dimensions, putting them in `dimens.xml` as `dp` (or `dip`) allowing me to get a scaled value in Java code with `Resources.getDimensionPixelSize()`.

Comment: About #2, how do you that distinction in the `dimens.xml` file (provide example if possible)? Reason 3 is very convincing.

Comment: @Nazgulled multiple files in qualified directories.  For instance, putting a `dimens.xml` in `res/values` for defaults and another in `res/values-ldpi` that includes the few I want to override for low density devices.

Comment: I though that was only available for the drawables folder. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You're welcome.  Qualifiers are usable (and extremely useful) on all resource directories.  If you look through the AOSP code, you'll see they make heavy use of this themselves as well!

Comment: @Devunwired, have you ever had an issue where a high density device references the values-ldpi/dimens.xml file? I have that issue when using the Samsung Galaxy Note - it uses the dimensions defined in values-ldpi/dimens.xml rather than the dimensions defined in values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml OR values-hdpi/dimens.xml Any suggestions?

Comment: @Enke I have not experienced that problem with the Note.  It is an hdpi device and usually picks the correct resources.

Comment: @Devunwired, I ended up fixing by removing the dimen elements in the custom values-sw320dpi folder and adding all the missing ones with various dimensions in them, so now I have /res/values ; /values-ldpi, /values-mdpi, /values-hdpi, /values-xhdpi, /values-small, /values-large and /values-xlarge and that seems to work.

Comment: I expanded your answer below. Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 23):

## Supplemental answer

@Devunwired lists 3 reasons to use `dimens.xml`. Here are the details of how to do that.

## 1. Reuse

If you set some `dp` or `sp` value in `dimens.xml` once like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textview_padding">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="large_text_size">30sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

you can reuse it throughout your app in multiple locations.

```
<TextView
    android:padding="@dimen/textview_padding"
    android:textSize="@dimen/large_text_size"
    ... />

<TextView
    android:padding="@dimen/textview_padding"
    android:textSize="@dimen/large_text_size"
    ... />
```

Then when you need to make a change, you only need to do it in one place.

**Notes**

- This is basically the same effect as using a style or theme.
- Be careful not to give two different views the same `dimen` value if they really shouldn't be. If you need to make changes to one set of views but not another, then you will have to go back to each one individually, which defeats the purpose.

## 2. Size Difference

- *@Devunwired called this **Density difference**, but if you are using `dp` (density independent pixels), this already takes care are the density difference problem for all but the most minor cases. So in my opinion, screen size is a more important factor for using `dimens.xml`.*

An `8dp` padding might look great on a phone, but when the app is run on a tablet, it looks too narrow. You can solve this problem by making two (or more) different versions of `dimens.xml`.

Right click your `res` folder and choose **New > Value resource file**. Then write in `dimens` and choose **Smallest Screen Width**. Write in **600** for the width (7” tablet). (There are other ways of choosing the sizes. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39302787/3681880) for more.)

[image]

This will make another `values` folder that will be used for devices whose smallest screen width is `600dp`. In the Android view the two `dimens.xml` files look like this.

[image]

Now you can modify them independently.

*values/dimens.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_default_padding">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

*values-sw600dp/dimens.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_default_padding">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

When using your `dimen` you only have to set it with the name you used in both `dimens.xml` files.

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:padding="@dimen/my_default_padding">

</LinearLayout>
```

The system will automatically choose the right value for you depending on the device the user is using.

## 3. Reading in from code

Sometimes it is a pain scaling programmatically between `px` and `dp` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108115/3681880) for how).

If you have a fixed `dp` value already defined in `dimens.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_dp_value">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then you can easily get it with

```
int sizeInPixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.my_dp_value);
```

and it will already be converted to pixels for whatever density device the user has.

Comment: this is very helpful. do you know of a way to force Android Studio to choose a specific dimens.xml for use during layout preview ?  I'm having trouble setting up a file for Samsung S7 landscape - I've made a sw640dp values file, but preview is selecting the default.

Comment: @orionelenzil, I don't know about the layout preview. You might try asking a new question about this. I will say that `sw600dp` is a more standard setting than `sw640dp`. This is the smallest width, so `600` will include `640` and any other larger sizes. Also, as long as you are getting the correct dimensions when running the app in the emulator or a device, I don't think it really matters if the preview doesn't work.

Comment: thanks @Suragch. I posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138505/android-difficulty-working-with-dimens-xml-files) .

Answer (score 4):

The `dimens.xml` file is used to keep all the hard-coded pixel values in one place.

Now, although you may not repeatedly use these values right now, it's still a good idea to to place them in `dimens.xml` for future reference. Besides, following a standard `Android` programming paradigm helps other developers to understand your code faster. This is much like the `strings.xml` where we place `String`s some of which end up being used only once! :)

Comment: It's not quite the same thing, the strings XML files also allows for internationalization, so makes more sense to have them separated from the code.

Comment: What kind of comment is that?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I meant, your comments didn't really help the Original Post's question nor is it entirely relevant to my post. I am just being honest! :)

Comment: Actually it is related, and it's useful. Thats why i voted for his comment. Also, he is the poster of the question. Asking him if he has a better answer for his own question is kinda pointless. Please don't take objective criticism the wrong way. It was just a valid, constructive sidenote, nothing personal. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if it can help you but I wrote a little java programe that allows you to duplicate a dimension xml file with a new desired value so that you no longer have to do it by hand line by line.

https://github.com/Drex-xdev/Dimensions-Scalable-Android