# How to disable landscape on small screens layout

Tags: java, android, layout, landscape

I'm allowing all possible orientation for my app both for **portrait and landscape** (small-normal-large-xlarge) but after testing it on a small screen, I just didn't like how it appears so, what I'm trying to do is disable landscape for small layouts. Is there a way to do this ?

All I found was changes to do on manifest file but I believe that by reconfiguring the manifest I will apply the changes to all layouts.

Comment: brother give your screen width then i will give you solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to put this in the `onCreate()` method of all your Activities (better yet, put it in a BaseActivity class and extend all your Activities from it)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   super.onCreate(bundle);

   if (isLargeDevice(getBaseContext())) {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
   } else {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
   }
}
```

You can use this method to detect if the device is a phone or tablet:

```
private boolean isLargeDevice(Context context) {
        int screenLayout = context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
        screenLayout &= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

        switch (screenLayout) {
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
            return false;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link you can check the type of device and set orientation as needed

[Android: allow portrait and landscape for tablets, but force portrait on phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone)

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically [handle runtime configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) like that

in your manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

in your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

     ///check the screen size and change it to potrait
    }
}
```

or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629127/2357411) to see  how to check the screen size and change it

Answer (score -1):

for example 480 screen size devices:Apply in oncreate method:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
if(width==480){

if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
} else setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


}
```