# How to change screen orientation, without creating a new activity on android?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I do not know if the title is correct, here is what happens.

I have an application which works differently on a phone and on a tablet, on a phone it shows as portrait on a tablet it shows as landscape.

To achieve this I created a class called CoreActivity which is extended by all my activities and does the following:

```
public class CoreActivity extends Activity {
    protected boolean _landscape = false;

    public boolean isPhone() {
        int layoutSize = getScreenLayoutSize();
        return (layoutSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL || layoutSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (isPhone() && !_landscape) {
            this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else {
            this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }


    protected int getScreenLayoutSize() {
        return (getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK);
    }
}
```

My problem occurs when I wish to show a screen on a phone setup on landscape mode, to do this I use the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    _landscape = true
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

The problem is, that on a phone, if the user is holding the phone on portrait mode (as one would, since most of the application is in portrait mode) then the activity gets created and destroyed and then recreated. But if they are holding it on landscape mode, then it is only created once.

My problem occurs because on the onCreate method I launch the threads that load data, and I also show fragments.

Is there a way to avoid this problem? is there a way to launch an activity from the start on portrait mode and not change it, or have it not create twice?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Activity always recreated after orientation changed.

Comment: did my answer work for you? :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27015879/1281930

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Recreating occurs just because you are forcing to, by calling `setRequestedOrientation` probably in order to set screen orientation. However you don't need to check and change it by code. You can do it via xml file. You can set different xml files depending on the screen size. But it is little bit hack so there is no guarantee in the future.

On the manifest file you can force by:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.my.example.MyActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>  // or portrait
```

So as far as I understand you want to force portrait for small sizes and landscape(or sensor) for larger screen sizes. But above configuration applies for all screen sizes. Here is the tricky part: `landscape` `portrait` `sensor` etc. are all integers defined [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT).
As you might guess you can write `android:screenOrientation=0` instead of `landscape`. What we know from beginning lessons of android, we can define integers in xml files then their values might vary on screen size. So..

You should first create different `integers.xml` files for different screen sizes. i.e.:

```
values
 - integers.xml
values-large
 - integers.xml
```

for `values/integers.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="orientation">1</integer>  // 1 for portrait
</resources>
```

for `values-large/integers.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="orientation">0</integer> // 0 for landscape
</resources>
```

and finally you you have to manipulate manifest file by:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.my.example.MyActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="@integer/orientation"/>  // read constant from xml files
```

You can also use `sensor` , `fullSensor`, `nosensor`, `locked`, `behind`, `reverseLandscape`, `reversePortait` options too. But I am warning you, this is a hack solution.

Comment: This does indeed set screen orientation, unfortunatelly it set it for ALL screen sizes, my problem is that I want different orientation for different screen sizes for most activities, and the same orientation for one activity, from what I have searched, there is no way to do this through androidmanifest

Comment: @Cruces check now mate. it is checkmate.

Comment: yep that seems to be EXACTLY what I wish to do, thanks a lot man that really helped

also this doesn't seem to be a hack solution, much cleaner than configChanges, and everyone and their mother has been warning me against using configChanges

Comment: Didn't work for me. The `@integer/orientation` is always taken from the `values/` directory even on devices where I know it should fetch it from a more qualified directory like `values-sw600dp/`. The strange thing is that if you get the integer at runtime via `getResources().getInteger(..)` it DOES pick from the more qualified directory. To me it seems like a bug in the installer that parses `AndroidManifest.xml`. It does not search for best matching resource using qualifiers like `-swNNNdp` when finding integer resources.

Comment: @EspenRiskedal interesting... Did you try on emulator too? and what is the device you are using for testing?

Comment: @bluebrain I tried on Genymotion tablet and phone images running Android 4.3, and on Xperia Z3 and a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 7.0.

Comment: @EspenRiskedal did you find solution on your question? because i made same thing in my app(like sw600) it doesn't work @integer/orientation thing.

Comment: @massaimara98 Sorry, I didn't find a solution that works in pure XML. I ended up using the `@integer/orientation` but calling a custom function from all my activities `onCreate(..)` that basically does `activity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.device_orientation); activity.setRequestedOrientation(orientation);`

Comment: @EspenRiskedal but as i know, its required 16 api level for setRequestedOrientation

Comment: @massaimara98 no it's API 1 I believe http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)

Comment: @EspenRiskedal oo awesome

Comment: This now gives a red-underline warning in Android Studio pointing out that you cannot use resource values in the Manifest that change between device configurations in this way. This makes a lot of sense since the Manifest is a static file in the APK so these references have to be resolved at build time.

Comment: @Tunga can you please reconfirm? Because I don't see a warning on A.S 2.1.3

Comment: @guness I'm seeing it on Android Studio 2.2 (stable). Note that you must actually override the value in at least one variation to see the warning: http://imgur.com/JT1voCQ

Answer (score 6):

Well, I found a solution to this issue, just declare:

```
android:screenOrientation="locked"
```

on every activity having this issue in the manifest.

And keep using `setRequestedOrientation()` programatically to define if landscape or portrait orientation within `onCreate()` method,

It will work! ;)

Comment: This was a great solution for me. I used the `locked` orientation on the main activity of our app and used the `behind` orientation on activities that can be launched from there. It only requires setting the orientation once throughout the entire app.

Answer (score 1):

If all your activites must have the same orientation on a device, you can start your application with a splash screen activity, set the orientation like in your current code and forward to your CoreActivity or any other activity in your App.

In your AndroidManifest.xml set

```
<activity
    android:name=".CoreActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="behind"/>
```

This will use the same orientation as the activity that's immediately beneath it in the activity stack.

Comment: not really what I was looking for, but I never knew about the 'behind' orientation, thank you

Comment: It actually worked for me. The option `locked` did not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"` to the `<activity>`-Tag inside of your AndroidManifest.xml?

This should prevent the system from restarting the Activity, but I am not sure whether this will actually work when forcing the orientation programatically. It's worth a shot though.

Comment: No, I'm sorry it doesn't seem to work, it still destroys the original activity and restarts the activity from oncreate

Answer (score 0):

try this in your `manifest.xml`...
this will stop the recalling the onCreate() multiple time while orientation changes...

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: this seems to work, I think it's the screenSize operator that made the difference, I need far more testing than what I've done so far with this mini app I'm trying, but I think  it's what I'm looking for, thanks for the answer, I'll try it

Comment: in my case it works fine..., try it, if it is suitable with  your requirement give a rating..

Comment: yes it does work, but from what I've researched configChanges is a bit of a no no to alter, still a solid solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want your activity don't recreate again when the device orientation changed.

You should use this in manifest for that activity.
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

And need to over ride the onConfigurationChanged function.
In side onConfigurationChanged you handle the different view for portrait and land scape. By using this your onCreate,onResume not call on orientation changed

Hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to handle this manually. Android has built it support for different screen sizes

check this link

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: the problem is, that the layouts for tablets are different to the ones for phone, the app is designed so that all layouts on tablet are viewed in landscape mode, and most layouts for phone are viewed on portrait mode, in order to implement portrait mode for tablets correctly and landscape for phones, it would take far too much time