# ViewModel Fragment Recreates On Screen Rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I'm building an application with latest android architecture components. I'm using firebase firestore as a database with jetpack navigation(Bottom nav). I'm successfully able to display data from DB. But Whenever I rotate mt screen the store fragment recreates & makes request to DB.

**Repo**

```
    override fun getAllStores() = callbackFlow<State<List<Store>>> {
    // Emit loading state
    send(State.loading())

    val listener = remoteDB.collection(Constants.COLLECTION_STORES)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, exception ->
            querySnapshot?.toObjects(Store::class.java)?.let { store ->
                // Emit success state with data
                offer(State.success(store))
            }
            exception?.let {
                // emit exception with message
                offer(State.failed(it.message!!))
                cancel()
            }
        }
    awaitClose {
        listener.remove()
        cancel()
    }

}.catch {
    // Thrown exception on State Failed
    emit(State.failed(it.message.toString()))
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

**ViewModel**

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@InternalCoroutinesApi
class StoreViewModel(private val repository: DBInterface = Repo()) : ViewModel() {

fun getAllStores() = repository.getAllStores()

}
```

**Store Fragment**

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@InternalCoroutinesApi
class StoreFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_store) {
private lateinit var storeAdapter: StoreAdapter
private val viewModel: StoreViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.store_title)

    setUpRV()

    // get all stores
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        getAllStores()
    }

}

private suspend fun getAllStores() {
    viewModel.getAllStores().collect { state ->
        when (state) {
            is State.Loading -> {
                store_progress.show()
            }

            is State.Success -> {
                storeAdapter.differ.submitList(state.data)
                store_progress.animate().alpha(0f)
                        .withEndAction {
                            store_rv.animate().alpha(1f)
                            store_progress.hide()
                        }

            }
            is State.Failed -> {
                store_progress.hide()
                activity?.toast("Failed! ${state.message}")
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun setUpRV() {
    storeAdapter = StoreAdapter()
    store_rv.apply {
        adapter = storeAdapter
        addItemDecoration(SpacesItemDecorator(16))
    }
}
```

}

**Main activity(Nav graph)**

```
@InternalCoroutinesApi
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    // init bottom navigation
    bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(nav_host_fragment.findNavController())
   
}
}
```

Every time it recreates my fragment. I don't want to save or retain any views using methods. Because ViewModel used to protect view on screen rotation. Kindly let me know any tips & tricks. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What makes you think the ViewModel is being recreated? Do you have logging on the ViewModel's creation? Flow by itself doesn't store any state (unlike `LiveData` for instance), so perhaps what you're seeing is related to that?

Comment: I have used LiveData for the same project & it works perfectly fine. When I'm using Flow I got struck by this. I have been using logging in the fragment. Do you have any suggestion to resolve this issue?.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Flow` in itself is not stateful - that is a key difference between it and `LiveData`. That means that after your `collect` completes, the next `collect` starts the `callbackFlow` from scratch.

This is precisely why the `lifecycle-livedata-ktx` artifact contains the [`asLiveData()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#aslivedata) extension that allows you to continue to use a `Flow` at the repository layer while maintaining the stateful (and Lifecycle) properties of `LiveData` for your UI:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@InternalCoroutinesApi
class StoreViewModel(private val repository: DBInterface = Repo()) : ViewModel() {
    fun getAllStores() = repository.getAllStores().asLiveData()
}
```

You'd change your UI code to continue to use `LiveData` and `observe()`.

Kotlin is working on [a `shareIn` operation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2047) that **would** allow your `ViewModel` to save the state of a `Flow`. That would allow you to use `Flow` at all layers of your app without requerying information from scratch when the Fragment/Activity that is calling `collect` gets destroyed and recreated.

Answer (score -3):

you can add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"` to your manifest for the activity. this should prevents restarts when orientation changes.

check this [site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015688/how-to-change-screen-orientation-without-creating-a-new-activity-on-android) are som infos.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks, mate

Comment: This has significant problems if you ever have different layouts based on screen size / any resource qualifier as you'd need to manually apply those changes and is really more of a workaround than an actual fix to the underlying issue.