# Get id of landscape layout

Tags: android, android-layout

[EDIT]I will try to simplify my question:

Is it possible to get a reference to a layout in res/layout-land/ when there is the same named layout in any other res/layout.../ folder?

I have a layout /res/layout/main.xml and I have a layout /res/layout-land/main.xml. 
In certain cases I would like to set the layout manually to the landscape layout.
How can I access the landscape layout via R.layout, so that I could set the landscape layout manually:

```
setContentView(R.layout.<<main(landscape)>>);
```

without renaming it to a distinct name.

For the downvoter, I tried the solution from here [force layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone) but this does not help with old Nexus 7 which gets recognized as phone in some cases.

[EDIT] This has nothing to do with my question, but for all the down voters who don't understand my question, currently I use this code:

```
 if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_phone)){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
 }
 else{
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
 }
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
```

but I would like to use code like this:

```
 if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_phone)){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    }
    else{
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_land);
    }
```

(No it's not an error here with the layout name having a _land suffix, I want to choose the tablet layout myself not let Android decide which layout to choose for tablets).

My question was, can I reference the layout res/layout-land/activity_fullscreen, without renaming it. OK, I give up.

Comment: Obviously this question is too hard to understand, so people down vote, it's a pity

Answer (score 1):

You set **same name** to both `protrait` and `landscape` layout. 
`Android` recognizes in which mode it is and based on that it selects
the required `layout`.

If you put `main.xml` in both `layout/res/layout-land/main.xml` and `layout/res/main.xml` you can set your layout as `setContentView(R.layout.R.layout.main);`, `android` will recognize devices mode and select the correct one

If you want to set it manually to landscape mode:
You can do it from `AndroidManifest` by putting `android:orientation="landscape"` to `activities` you want to show in `landscape mode`

To set it for **different tablet sizes** you can create also *different folders* based on that:

If `tablet layout` requires at least `600dp of screen width`, you should place it in `layout-sw600dp/`

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information

Comment: Thanks, please reread my question. I need the activity to run in portrait on phones, and landscape on tablets, but the automatically chosen landscape layout is not applied correctly in all cases. I have the following case: Nexus 7(old) in portrait mode, when app starts, it is set to landscape correctly, but with the wrong layout chosen (not the tabled landscape layout but with phone landscape layout), so I want to set it to tablet landscape layout manually, as automatically it does not work

Comment: So I am not asking how to set activity to landscape only, or how to set layout so android can choose the right one, I want to set the layout by myself using R.layout.id without renaming the landscape layout to another name.

Comment: @AndyZ check my updated answer, you can create folders based on the `width` or `height` of the devices also

Comment: thanks, I know all that, I asked for a way to get a reference to the layout in res/layout-land/main.xml. If it is not possible to reference the same named layout, then please tell me.

Comment: You can do that by checking programatically for the devices `width` and `setContentLayout` based on that