# Android preconfigure lock to portrait on phone and allow landscape on tablet

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am aware of configuration change in manifest. I am also aware of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793611/2746924) from 2013.

My question is, can this be done using Gradle rather than having to use code in runtime?