# Phone & Tablet module

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, landscape-portrait

I'm using "layout-600dp" from diferenciate the smartphone from tablet of 7".

But the tablet from 10" must have a landscape xml (the others are in portrait) and my androidmanifest.xml already have:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

in the `<activity>`.

How make it?

Comment: the perfect idea would be make it with a diferent java class, for make another functions, but i don't know how make it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: allow portrait and landscape for tablets, but force portrait on phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone)

Comment: i thinked use the tablet & phone module, but i'm not sure if would work