# Programatically determining whether device is a Phone or Tablet

Tags: android

I've got an application with an activity containing 2 layouts:

- layout/activity_main.xml - "phone mode", with a single view inside (a list)
- layout-w900dp/activity_main.xml - "tablet mode" with 2 views (list and details)

Normally, I check the detail side of functionality with:

```
if (findViewById(R.id.application_detail_container) != null) {
    // The detail container view will be present only in the
    // large-screen layouts (res/values-w900dp).
    // If this view is present, then the
    // activity should be in two-pane mode.
    mTwoPane = true;
}
```

How can I convert such approach to use data binding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could simply define a resource in your strings.xml file

In values/strings.xml.

```
<bool name="is_tablet">false</bool>
```

In values-w900dp/string.xml

```
<bool name="is_tablet">true</bool>
```

Access this resource from any where in your code. This should solve your issue.

> For example :

```
 boolean isTablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet);
```

Comment: That's Ok, but the problem is that in some cases I have the "details" view and in some other cases I don't have it.

Comment: Yeah but that details view is added only if it is tablet right? If it is not a tablet the details view won't be there.

Comment: yes, but my current code calls `detail.update()` in the case it's a tablet and the user pressed on an item from the list. Wouldn't I get a compile error if I try to use `binding.detail.update()`? Should I use another variable for the detail view (with its own binding)?

Comment: No there wont be any compilation error. Only change you need to do is : if(isTablet) details.update();

Comment: is `w900dp` the definitive way to do it these days? A few years ago it used to be `sw600dp`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40637603/550471

Comment: It depends on the requirement, if you see in the question @LaurIvan has provided alternate resources only for w900dp folder. Hence he will need to provide isTablet true only for the devices which is using alternate resource.