# Force set orientation to Landscape for an activity even when auto rotate is enabled

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation

I am setting the orientation with `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE)`

However when I check for the orientation before setting this up using `Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`
I am getting value 1 which is potrait.

Then I set the orientation with the code. Still I am getting the value 1, also the android system is looking in Layout folder(potrait) for the layout rather than layout-large-land. 
So conclusion is, How to force set the orientation to Landscape?

Comment: if the device is not `large`, then it won't use values from `layout-large-land` in any case. So make sure you have a `layout-land` as well

Answer (score 2):

You can force set orientation in `AndroidManifest.xml` for  `Activity`:

```
<activity
    android:name="<name_of_your_activity>"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    ...
```

**Update**
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone) question.

Comment: Actually I want to set Potrait orientation for Phones and Landscape for Tablets. So I cannot set the orientation through Manifest

Answer (score 0):

create bool.xml in values

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

create another bool.xml in values-sw600dp

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

then in your activity

```
boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
if (tabletSize) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
} else {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: Dude, I am already getting that boolean and tried this code. However this is not setting the orientation to potrait. I have confirmed this with `Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`. And even before setting setrequestedorientation and after that the value remains 1

Comment: no, I didnt set orientation Attribute for this activity in manifest

Comment: Where should this be called?

Comment: In your activity after setContentView()

Comment: can you post your code on pastebin.com so that i can have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127894/discussion-between-kannan-sjd-and-android-jack).