# Creating AndroidManifest for tablet only

Tags: java, android

I need to restrict landscape orientation on phone and allow it on tablet. I can use configChanges:orientation within **activity** tag and process it in code. But can I create AndroidManifest file for tablet where I'll allow landscape orientation and use two manifests for phone and tablet?

Comment: `can I create AndroidManifest file ` No .Its a auto GEN.

Comment: Duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to make two manifests for one app. You will have to use same manifest file. But what can you do is multiple flavors. You can specify your manifest or gradle with respect to each type. See the [official](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) docs.