# React-native Android Set only Portrait Mobile Phones Otherwise tablets shows landScape and Portrait

Tags: react-native

I have a small problem in this case in my app I set default Portrait.But now this time i want show Portrait and landScape in Tabs  not only Mobile phone .In mobile phones show only Portrait(Force Update to Portrait).

I followed this link but I am getting this error and i dd't understand how can we create folders where can we place the data.
I followed this link: but i didn't get

[Android: allow portrait and landscape for tablets, but force portrait on phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Go to the Android folder inside your RN Project,add `values-sw600dp` and `values-xlarge` to the following path:

```
android/app/src/main/res/values-sw600dp
android/app/src/main/res/values-xlarge
```

then add `bools.xml` to `values`,`values-sw600dp`,`values-xlarge`. the result:

[image]

2.Add code to  MainActivity.java in the path `android/app/src/main/java/com/[your project name]/MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Main Activity or Main Application.Java Which file inside add oncreate methode

Comment: But I have get an Error

Comment: MainActivity.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                                ^
  symbol:   variable ActivityInfo
  location: class MainActivity
2 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: How Can I Solve this

Comment: This is the full code of the [MainActivity.java](https://pastebin.com/xHs9XMTd), make sure you just paste the code in the right place.

Comment: check out this [Repo](https://github.com/ufxmeng/ScreenOrientation) to see if it works on your computer.

Comment: when i was check in my mobile it's shoing portrait and I pad also Portrait not showing Landscape

Comment: how can Modify the Design Changes getting Portrait .  When i was Getting Portrait LandScape getting few Design Issues Above Case based Is it possible Change Design Issues. How is is possible

Comment: Now Agian Getting Error error: cannot find symbol
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class Bundle
  location: class MainActivity
1 error
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: Open Android studio to auto import all the reference, or just copy  them from my repo

Comment: OKAy I fixed My Issue But When I was Check in Tab it have some Design Issues how Can i fit in Only Or change in Tab please give an suggestion

Comment: in This based Up on How can i Solve SplitView on Tablet or I pad not Phones

Comment: The imports you need to add to the top of the `MainActivity.java` are:
`import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;` and `import android.os.Bundle;`. It took @faddah and I a little while to figure that out.