# Device Based SplitView in react-native(only for Tablets and iPad's )

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, splitview

I am Working on a sample application. I've designed my app based on View Container. By using the below cases i designed my app in Portrait  Mode for mobile Phones(iOS/Android) and also Designed both Portrait and LandScape Modes for iPad/Tablets.

- In Android I followed this Case in
- [React-native Android Set only Portrait Mobile Phones Otherwise tablets shows landScape and Portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613757/react-native-android-set-only-portrait-mobile-phones-otherwise-tablets-shows-lan)
- In iOS I followed this case
- In iOS just set in `Xcode -> general -> Development info -> Device Orientation` and select `Portrait` for iPhone and `Portrait , LandscapeLeft and LandScapeRight` for iPad.

Now i want to Design splitView for both iPad and Tablets in  both Portrait and Landscape modes. I've searched on google but don't find any information. I would like to know how can i design it(Split View) in both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Wix's react-native-navigation provides a native extension to SplitView, but not for Android. (https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/docs/docs/layout-types.md)

I have not tried the react-native-split-view package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-split-view) but it reports to work on iOS and Android.