# Landscape layout file is loaded, while portrait mode is forced. (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently developing an app, in which phones have forced portrait mode, while tablets support portrait mode as well as landscape mode. Some pages the layouts have respective landscape versions in the layout-land folder.

**The problem**

While using the app on a phone (so portrait only) and when autorotate on the phone is enabled, the landscape layout file gets loaded while the app is displayed as portrait mode.

**When does this occur**

To recreate this behaviour I open an activity and rotate the device. Then when I navigate to another activity, or close and open the application, the landscape layout gets loaded.

**Method of forcing portrait mode**

To force portrait mode on phones, I call

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

in my BaseActivity `onCreate` method.

**Other details**

targetSdkVersion: 26
using support library 26.0.0

Thank you for helping!

***Edit 1:***

Unfortunately using (a combination of) the following settings in the manifest file gives the same behaviour.

- `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"`
- `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`
- `android:configChanges="orientation"`

***Edit 2:***

I've now tested on multiple devices (emulator, One plus, Motorola, Samsung and some more) and this oddity only happens on a Samsung A5 (api 23) for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is other Activities are also have that code?
I meant, other Activity that doesn't extends BaseActivity?

I would prefer to set in `AndroidManifest.xml` file in each activity tag like >> `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Answer (score 0):

add this line `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in your project manifest file inside activity. Hope it work well.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test_edit"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.DesignDemo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Portrait orientation, but can be either normal or reverse portrait based on the device sensor.

Refer this link for more details :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned,

> phones have forced portrait mode, while tablets support portrait mode
>   as well as landscape mode

Set screen orientation in `manifest` will not work.
Use `layout-land-sw600dp`, `layout-land-sw720dp` folders for landscape view for tablets. Also please take a look at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone)