# Some devices are taking different orientation (for brief moment) then what I set in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, tablet, screen-orientation

> I have checked every possible solutions in all stack overflow
> solutions and other web sites also but no luck.
>
> My Requirement is :
>
> Phone - only portrait mode
>
> Tablet - portrait and landscape mode.

So tried using following:

For finding device if it is a Phone or a Tablet I used

```
if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_sw_600dp_size)) {

    intent = new Intent(LauncherEmptyActivity.this, SplashActivityTablet.class);
    
} else {

    intent = new Intent(LauncherEmptyActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
}
```

And for my requirement if I set orientation as following for all activities
(all orientation set at Manifest, tried also through programming but no luck)

1. LauncherEmptyActivity  - Set Sensor

   ```
                       (or Set any of these above -  "nosenser", "userSensor", "unspecified", "fullUser", "user")
   ```
2. SplashActivity - Set Portrait
3. SplashActivityTabet - Same As LauncherEmptyActivity

Result :

- Application open in both portrait and landscape mode in Tablet (**Expected O/P**)
- **But for Phone If it is held in landscape mode then - SplashActivity will be landscape for brief moment and
  then it will be in portrait**
  (This is the issue and I dont want that for brief moment).

Issue happens in

- Device - Nexus 5x (Nought),
- Emulator - Google Pixel (Oreo)

But working fine in Device - Moto G4 Plus (Nought)

> This is for more explanation purpose, Following solution perfectly
> fine If my requirement is
>
> (working fine for all above devices mentioned)
>
> Phone - only portrait
>
> Tablet - only landscape

1. LauncherEmptyActivity  - Set Portrait
2. SplashActivity - Set Portrait
3. SplashActivityTablet - Set landscape

(all orientation set at Manifest)

Result : Correct As Expected

Comment: Please guys, I have this issue and If you are giving minus marking then at least mention the reason for that in comments, because this problem is real and I am facing it, And If any more info require then let me know