# Phone only portrait, tablet all orientations: Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityInfo'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-orientation

I have an Android app build with the newest version of Android Studio.

I want to allow only portrait mode on phone but all orientations on tablets.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793611/9548591) answer and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39302787/9548591) post.

I made everything as described.

Then I opened the file `activity/MainActivity.java`.

I looked for this line of code: `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

Then I added the following code below this code:

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Here's a small snippet:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

`ActivityInfo` has a red color with the following error message:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityInfo'

It also shows a blue information:

> android.content.pm.ActivityInfo? ⌥⏎

Why that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the following line at the top of your file below package name to import ActivityInfo:
`import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;`