# Android Studio FATAL EXPECTION : main | I cant find solution

Tags: java, android

In this forum that's three question about that I know, but none solved my problem. They didnt help me.

I'm trying learn android, I coded something but it doesnt work on my phone anytime. Everytime it says "has stopped working"

my codes :

Java

```
package com.example.murathan.oyun;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button javauyu, javasavas, javayemek;
    TextView javaeylem, javaistatistik;
    Karakter k;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        k = new Karakter();
        javauyu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_uyu);
        javasavas = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_savas);
        javayemek = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_yemek);
        javaeylem = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_eylem);
        javaistatistik = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_istatistik);
        javauyu.setOnClickListener(this);
        javayemek.setOnClickListener(this);
        javasavas.setOnClickListener(this);
        k.kilo = 50;
        k.action = 10;
        k.attackD = 80;
        javaistatistik.setText(k.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == javauyu.getId())
        {
            javaeylem.setText(k.komutuyu());
        }
        else if (v.getId() == javasavas.getId())
        {
            javaeylem.setText(k.komutsavas());
        }
        else if (v.getId() == javayemek.getId())
        {
            javaeylem.setText(k.komutye());
        }
        javaistatistik.setText(k.toString());
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_istatistik"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@string/size"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@string/pad"
            android:text="@string/istatistik"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_uyu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@string/size"
                android:padding="@string/pad"
                android:text="@string/b_uyu"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_yemek"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@string/size"
                android:padding="@string/pad"
                android:text="@string/b_yemek"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_savas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@string/size"
                android:padding="@string/pad"
                android:text="@string/b_savas"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_eylem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@string/size"
            android:padding="@string/pad"
            android:text="@string/eylemyap"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and Crash (LogCat)

```
08-18 21:17:45.816 22618-22618/com.example.murathan.oyun E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.murathan.oyun, PID: 22618
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.murathan.oyun/com.example.murathan.oyun.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 14 to dimension: type=0x3
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:87)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:83)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:177)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.murathan.oyun.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

please help me to solve my problem, i'm researching since 2 days but i cant solve that.

if there's any writing problem im sorry, im not English so I cant write very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your issue

`android:padding="@string/pad"`

padding and textsize need to get a dimension like 10dp, not a string

Comment: For @OnlyM, you can know the reason why the error occurs from the error messages starting with 'Caused by: '.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml you have set

```
android:textSize="@string/size"
android:padding="@string/pad"
```

instead of set 
`@string/size` you have to use `@dimen/size`  [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128178/how-to-use-dimens-xml-in-android)