# How to set an unique height for all the items of a RecyclerView grid that can be easily changed at runtime?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `RecyclerView` with a grid layout, every item is a `CardView` and I want to set an unique height for every card, in particular this height must be modifiable at runtime through a method/property of the adpter and the new value must be applied instantaneously to all items of the grid. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dimens.xml and there for to define an item with name and height which you want and then only call in the xml at layouts.
Here you have the link with answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47321385/9560126