# Is "sp" also accepted in the dimens.xml for a Kotlin Android app?

Tags: android, xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>`

`<dimen name="min_text_height">48dp</dimen> </resources>`

In the place of 48dp, can sp also be used as a viable size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes it can](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension).

You might also find useful:

- [How to use dimens.xml in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128178/how-to-use-dimens-xml-in-android)

Comment: Thank you very much! and I would assume that also goes for ``in``, ``mm``, ``pt``, and ``px``, right?

Comment: No problem! Yes, according to the documentation (which is the link attached to my sentence *Yes it can* in the answer) seems that all those units are supported.

Comment: Ah, okay! I should probably hit those as my go-to if I have questions. Thanks again!