# Android - difficulty working with dimens.xml files

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I'm working in Android Studio and attempting to use the layout preview and a dimens.xml file to adjust the layout for a Samsung S7 phone.  I'm using multiple dimens.xml files selected by minimum screen width.

I have three questions:

1) is it possible to force android studio to use a particular dimens.xml file ?  or even see definitively which one it's using.  I'm considering putting a value in that's the name of the containing values folder and logging it out, for example.

2) How can I set up a virtual device to reliably emulate a Samsung S7?  The S7 screen is 2560 x 1440, and 5.1" on the diagonal. I set up a new virtual device with these specs, but the layout looks much different in Android Studio than it does on the real device.

3) Given the pixel resolution and diagonal length, how can I calculate the minimum screen width in dp units?

Comment: It looks like the smallest width is `360dp`. ([link](https://material.io/devices/))

Comment: For your second question, you might want to post comparative screen shots with red free hand circles that show what you are talking about.

Comment: I still don't have answers for 1) and 2), but for 3) if you have the device "density", the dp = the pixel resolution divided by the density. So [for a samsung S7, density = 4.0] (https://material.io/devices/) so the dp is 2560 x 1440 / 4 = 640 x 360.  I also realized that the layout editor was choosing the dimens.xml file based on the screen width _in portrait_, even tho my layout was landscape.  .. Which is what @Suragch indicated two comments up.

Comment: If you want it to choose the dimension based on the orientation (rather than the smallest width), then you can do that also. Smallest width is used for differentiating phones from tablets, not for orientation.