# Why there is a difference between my app in a real device and the layout preview in android studio

Tags: android, xml

app description :-
simple app with listView (orientation : horizontal)

the problem is :-
when i run the app on a real device , i found that all views direction get reversed

this is an item on android studio:-
[app preview on android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVzPt.png)

but when it run on a real device it look like this 
[app on a real device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVzPt.png)

this is my layout (item.xml) code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout_id"
    android:padding="20dp">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mag_id"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7.1"
        android:textColor="#302f2f"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/country_id"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Egypt"
        android:textColor="#302f2f"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/date_id"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="July 21,2018"
        android:textColor="#302f2f"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

i want to display the same design from android studio preview on the real device 
with the same view direction.

so what is the problem and how i can fix this.

Comment: You can make the preview change to right to left locale

Comment: Its because of the difference between your mobile size and preview layout size.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to difference between the screen size and display resolution, the layout that you're designing in the studio might look good on that exact screen size or resolution that you've selected in the layout editor, but that might not be the case for every device, your device in this case.
You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508493/when-should-the-dimens-xml-file-be-used-in-android/7508587#7508587) thread for more detailed solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

you should check two or three things:

1- is your `ListView` parent layout has `layoutDirection` in XML?

2- have you called the method `getWindow().setLayoutDirection(LayoutDirection.RTL)` any where in your code?

3- if your list `activity` or `fragment` does not have number 2 then you should check your adapter class to see if there is any code written about `ItemView` direction.

4- if non of this is relevant for you please try changing preview android version and preview size.

hope this helps.